# trying to get formula to get standard deviation of last 5 values

Tags: google-sheets

Column A has the values to get standard deviation and will be added to daily want to be able to get the standard deviation for the last 5 values as the data increases.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=STDEV(QUERY(SORT(A2:A; ROW(A2:A); ); 
 "where Col1 is not null limit 5"; ))
```

[image]